# java.lang.NullPointerException because I don't have permission to access the table

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, nullpointerexception, hql

I have a project in Java EE. When I access the table from database it returns error, here's the HQL query :

```
select b from Blacklist b inner join fetch b.users u where b.type ilike :type order by b.date desc
```

and this the error message :

```
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache$HQLQueryPlanKey.<init>(QueryPlanCache.java:193)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:87)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createQuery(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:139)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at doku.edp.trasactions.Eds2UtilityBean.getFieldDataFromBlacklist(Eds2UtilityBean.java:325)
18:18:10,694 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor522.invoke(Unknown Source)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_405857447.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_405857447.java)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_405857447.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_405857447.java)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
18:18:10,695 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
```

I see my Postgres DB, when I'm doing `SELECT` query to the table, then I get a warning:

> permision denied for relation whitelist.

Does the warning on Postgres is the cause of this error?

Comment: Can we see the code causing an error?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please precise - what is the code you're executing, how are you executing it, paste your stacktrace, etc. At this point we have no idea even what is your problem.

Comment: im sorry guys.. , here's the error, i already edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only assuming as you haven't posted any Java code but looks like your NullPointer which is probably a ResultSet which dosen't contain any results is because you don't have the right permissions to read/write onto the relation 'whitelist'. I'd check what username your using to login to the database against which username your using for the jdbc connection.

If you post your java code we can see if the NullPointer is because of an empty result set which you are then trying to manipulate or because of something else.

First question i've answered so sorry if its wordy.

Comment: thanks for your answer,, i have been edited the question with the error message. thanks

Comment: Hi Diaz - You tried to run the query on the postgres database and you got the permission denied error? Looking at your query the table or relation your looking to query is 'Blacklist' while the permission denied error mentions 'whitelist' not Blacklist.

Comment: yes, u right , i dont have any msg of error on jboss that contains permission denied. so that's not the main problem. my error indicates the query fail to access the blacklist table.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack, we could say that something wrong is with the query that you have created. 
To be sure i would add `as` and remove the `ilike` and the `select` clause from it.

```
from Blacklist as b inner join fetch b.users as u where b.type like :type order by b.date desc
```

The ilike operator do exists in [Expression](http://docs.atlassian.com/hibernate2/2.1.8/api/net/sf/hibernate/expression/Expression.html), but i am not aware about HQL try to execute about query.